# TypeScript compiler API: find which file a type came from

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Given a `ts.Program` and the name of a type, is it possible to find which file the type came from? The type being queried will always exist in the program and will be exported from the main entry point.

I don't necessarily need specific code here, just which APIs to start with or an example of something similar. Using `program.getTypeChecker()` to get a `ts.TypeChecker` may be relevant, but none of its methods seemed to provide an obvious way to go from *just a type name* to something which would tell where the type was defined.

(VS Code "go to definition" is conceptually similar, but the code runs through several layers of abstraction and wasn't a useful example.)

Answer (score 1):

From a given type you can get the symbol and from the symbol you can get the declarations. From the symbol's declarations you can get all source files the type is from (ex. declaration merging may cause a type to have multiple declarations and those declarations may live in another file).

Here's some example code (untested, but I think it will work):

```
const symbol = type.getSymbol()!; // todo: you should handle for when undefined
const declarations = type.declarations;
const sourceFiles = Array.from(new HashSet(declarations.map(d => d.getSourceFile()));
```

Comment: The problem is I don't have a type. I just have the name of a type.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. What does that type name look like so you can tell where that name is from? Does it look like `import("some/path/to-file.ts").SomeDeclaration` where the path is relative to the root of the module? Or is it the name of a global type (ex. `Array`)?

Comment: The name comes from a list (generated by another tool) of all type names exported from `my-package`. In theory you could do `import { Foo } from 'my-package'`, and `my-package`'s index file and everything it references are in the TS program. If there's not a more direct API for this, maybe there's a way to generate a fake root-level import of the type name and see what it resolves to?

Comment: Oh, I see. Is it possible to just get the exports of the package yourself? You could do `const fileSymbol = typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(sourceFile);` on the main source file of your package, then inspect the `exports` property on `fileSymbol`. From those export symbols you can follow them along to the declaration.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, with the above information, given `import {foo} from 'foo-lib'` I can find where `foo` came from, f.e. `foo-lib/path/to/foo.ts`. Is this right?

Comment: Looking for a working solution as well. I need to create a script to get rid of all the barrel imports in the app. But there are 4000 imports to replace by the full path. How can this be achieved? So far, i did not manage to do it. Thanks in advance!